# IntegrityError at /accounts/signup in django when trying to signup

Tags: python, django

this is my blog : http://gorani-dncvb.run.goorm.io/

I am trying to build a signup page for my django blog.

I finished writing codes for template/view/form/url, and successfully connected to the page : http://gorani-dncvb.run.goorm.io/accounts/signup.

So I came to think there is no problem in template/url. but the problem arises after trying signup, It saids :

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/signup
UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username
```

and this is my view code :

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=raw_password)
        return redirect("post_list")
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form':form})
```

and this is form code :

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password',)
```

(I didn't used UserCreateForm on purpose)

There's definitely no overlapping another user, so why I'm seeing this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for duplicating the user is that django creates the user when saving the form.
When a form is a child of ModelForm, saving it will create a new object of the model class related to the form.

Just delete or comment the code lines for user creation and it wil work fine:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
        return redirect("post_list")
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form':form})
```

Best regards.

Comment: thanks, I removed the lines you said, and now there's no error message refered above.

Comment: but after signing up - after logging in as ID just made, it saids 'username and password doesn't match'. but it works as another ID made from django shell. Can you help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Try setting the user password after saving the form.
I've edited the answer to reflect the changes.